# Threads, como animar un label en JavaFX?

Tags: hilos, javafx, animación, fxml

Estoy en un trabajo escolar, tengo que hacer la animación de una "pelota", que no es más que un label con un estilo en CSS que me convierte el label en un circulo de color rojo.

Tengo que hacer que la pelota se mueva a cierta dirección, eso ya lo tengo.
Pero se me ocurrió probar en mover 2 pelotas a la vez, cada pelota con su propio hilo...

*Cree una clase, llamada "movimiento", la cual hereda de **Thread**, en la cual recibo un Label, un AnchorPane (Para saber las coordenadas de los bordes, que son limitantes) y un booleano, para saber si mover izquierda o derecha, si ejecuto solamente un hilo, el programa va bien, pero si lanzo los hilos, es decir, 2 instancias de la clase **movimiento**, una funciona perfecto, pero la otra se para.*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podría hacer para que las dos "pelotas" se muevan?

El primer hilo es la pelota V, y el segundo hilo de la pelota A.

Este es mi codigo:

**Clase principal**

```
public class U3HilosAnimar0002 extends Application {


@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("pelot.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

**El controlador del FXML**

Aquí recibo el clic del boton Start, para iniciar el movimiento

```
package u3hilosanimar0002;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;



public class PelotController implements Initializable {
@FXML
private Label lbl;
@FXML
private Button btnStart;
@FXML
private AnchorPane APfondo;
@FXML
private Label lbl2;
@FXML
private AnchorPane AP2;

/**
 * Initializes the controller class.
 */
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO



}    

@FXML
private void startHilo(ActionEvent event) throws InterruptedException {

    Movimiento m1 = new Movimiento(lbl,APfondo,true);
    Movimiento m2 = new Movimiento(lbl2,APfondo,false);


  m1.start();
          System.out.println("Segundo Hilo");

    m2.start();


}


}
```

**Clase movimiento que hereda de Thread**

```
    package u3hilosanimar0002;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

/**
 *
 * @author ESPINO
 */

public class Movimiento extends Thread {


int c;
Label pelota = new Label();
 AnchorPane AP;
private boolean direccion;


Movimiento(Label lbl, AnchorPane APfondo,boolean direccion) {
    c=5;
    this.pelota = lbl;
    this.AP = APfondo;
    this.direccion = direccion;//flse left , true derech
}


@Override
public  void  run(){

    while(true){

        if(this.pelota.getLayoutX()+this.pelota.getWidth()>AP.getWidth()||this.pelota.getLayoutX()<0){

            //hará que rebote a la direccion opuesta, cuando llegué a la derecha del todo
         c*=(-1);   
           //Thread.interrupted();
            //break;
        }            

        try {


            //if(direccion){
              this.pelota.setLayoutX(this.pelota.getLayoutX()+c);
              //direccion = false;
            //}
            //else{
              //  this.pelota.setLayoutX(this.pelota.getLayoutX()-c);
                //direccion =false;
            //}


            sleep(35);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Movimiento.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }  


    }

}


}
```

**FXML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.net.URL?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" fx:id="APfondo" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="645.0" styleClass="mainFxmlClass" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="u3hilosanimar0002.PelotController">
    <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@pelot.css" />
    </stylesheets>
   <children>
      <AnchorPane fx:id="AP2" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="645.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
      <Label fx:id="lbl" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" layoutX="278.0" layoutY="177.0" prefHeight="46.0" prefWidth="44.0" text="V" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font size="28.0" />
         </font></Label>
      <Button fx:id="btnStart" layoutX="253.0" layoutY="345.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#startHilo" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="95.0" text="Start" />
      <Label fx:id="lbl2" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" layoutX="278.0" layoutY="98.0" prefHeight="46.0" prefWidth="44.0" text="A" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font size="28.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando trabajes con aplicaciones de JavaFX debes evitar actualizar la interfaz gráfica desde hilos diferentes del JavaFX Application Thread. Este es el thread principal de las aplicaciones JavaFX y es el encargado de manejar todas las tareas referentes a la UI. Si intentas hacer estas actualizaciones en threas independientes, en ocasiones se lanzan excepciones y en otras, como la tuya, tienes comportamientos raros y al parecer inexplicables.

**Salución:**
La línea donde actualizas la posición del Label ejecútala con el métodos [Platform.runLater()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-), así:

```
try {
    Platform.runLater(() -> this.pelota.setLayoutX(this.pelota.getLayoutX() + c));       
    sleep(35);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Movimiento.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Puedes conocer un poco más sobre concurrencia en JavaFX [aquí](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm).

Comment: Ya lo probé, funciona perfectamente,
le echaré un ojo a ese enlace... Gracias
También pude correjir un cambio de texto aun componente (por si alguien pudiera tener ese problema).

Comment: Por nada. Que bueno que te pude ayudar.